# Properties of infinities, infinitesimals

Tags: number-theory, pi, nested-radicals

When I was calculating Pi value with Viete's method, One method is single multiplication of
 $2^n\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+... n\text{ times}}}}$. 
There is another way when we start with equilateral triangle it turns about to be $3\cdot 2^n\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\dots (n-1)\text{ times}}}}$ and at the end of the nest $\sqrt3$.

Comparing both this method separately returns smaller and smaller values for nested square roots. As everyone can understand even though both methods lead to infinitismal numbers both these small numbers are different and when multipled by 2^n or 3*2^n they result in $Pi$.

My doubt is both the infinitismal numbers are different and the numbers $2^n limit n \to\infty$
and $3*2^n limit n\to\infty$ are also different.

As we are deducing $\pi$ by 2 different methods, it must be true that, both infinitesimal numbers are different and also infinitely big numbers are also should be different. Can anyone clarify? 
So infinite number $2^n$ where $n$ approaches infinity and $3*2^n$ where $n$ approaches infinity should be different. Please clarify from this perspective

Comment: "As everyone can understand even though both methods lead to infinitismal numbers" That's not how limits work - infinitesimals don't actually exist as more than a linguistic device. (That's not actually true, there are frameworks for making infinitesimals rigorous such as [nonstandard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis), but that's not really relevant to this question - for now you should focus on the standard analysis picture.) Similarly, the "infinite numbers" you're talking about aren't actually there.

Comment: As the first series gives $2^n\sin(2^{-n}\pi)$ and the second $3⋅2^n\sin(2^{-n}\frac\pi3)$, you always know what the "infinitesimals" (or i-small numbers for i-large $n$) are and how fast the products approach $\pi$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber couldn't have said it any better. As this is not in reference to nonstandard analysis, infinitesimals do not exist in the real numbers. Why? If there exists a very small real number e and a very large finite real number M, there has to exist n such that ne > M. But by the definition of an infinitesimal, no real number n can exist such that the product of e and n is greater than 1! Therefore, an infinitesimal is not a real number. In this problem, by the limit approaching infinity in the reals, all that matters is that both limits approach the same value asymptotically.

Comment: @Eliot : There is the Nelson variant of NSA where infinitesimals and infinities are just "not observable" members of the real number line, numbers that will never occur in numerical computation, regardless of what multi-precision mechanism you use. Astonishingly, such a separation of numbers in standard and non-standard ones can be done in extension of the usual set theory. Then indeed there are integers larger than all standard integers and their reciprocals are infinitesimals.

Comment: @LutzL "Astonishingly, such a separation of numbers in standard and non-standard ones can be done in extension of the usual set theory." I wouldn't say that's astonishing; a direct consequence of compactness is that we can automatically go from a set theory $T$ to a "two-tiered" theory $T'$ which intuitively describes models of $T$ embedded in their nontrivial ultrapowers. This isn't to detract from Nelsonian and other approaches to NSA, but I think it's misleading and ultimately unhelpful to cast them as more mysterious than they actually are.

Comment: Indeed, it's a point in their *favor* that they're so easy to develop.